# Duplicate records when using tail and logrotate in FluentD within output_data to Elastic Search

Tags: fluentd

At the moment, I have the issue that was describe following:

1. I setup FluentD with Elastic Search + Kibana via that URL example:
   http://www.fluentd.org/guides/recipes/elasticsearch-and-s3
2. When configured successfully, I test tail process in access.log and error.log.
   I see dupplicate records in Elastic Search after FluentD (td-agent) following tail and parse every line in log completed.

Example:

**1/ In error.log file, I have following:**
[Thu Mar 13 19:04:13 2014] [error] [client 50.0.134.125] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico

**2/ After following tail error.log, FluentD will POST that line to Elastic Search with format JSON :**
[Thu Mar 13 19:04:13 2014] [error] [client 50.0.134.125] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico (imagine JSON on elastic search) -> Check on kibana: Size of Record = 1

**3/ I add 1 line to the bottom of the content in error.log:**

[Thu Mar 13 19:04:13 2014] [error] [client 50.0.134.125] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico (old line in 1/)

[Thu Mar 14 15:02:23 2014] [error] [client 50.0.134.125] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon2.ico (new line was added)

**4/ After following tail error.log, FluentD will POST those lines to Elastic Search with format JSON :**
[Thu Mar 13 19:04:13 2014] [error] [client 50.0.134.125] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico (imagine JSON on elastic search) -> Check on kibana: Size of Record = 3. That content :

[Thu Mar 13 19:04:13 2014] [error] [client 50.0.134.125] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico (imagine JSON on elastic search) -> Check on kibana: Size of Record = 1

[Thu Mar 13 19:04:13 2014] [error] [client 50.0.134.125] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon.ico (**old line dupplicate in 1/**)

[Thu Mar 14 15:02:23 2014] [error] [client 50.0.134.125] File does not exist: /var/www/favicon2.ico (new line was added)

So I see the record within [Thu Mar 13 19:04:13 2014] is dupplicate. I think this issue is caused by FluentD when parsing.

---

My config file in td-agent.conf:

[image]

---

Note: All is reproduce in my localhost. Don't have fluentD plugin secure forward from other servers
Thanks.
Regards,
Minh

Comment: Your configuration is not complete, and suggests that you are using a copy plugin to copy the emitted message to multiple destinations.   This could be leading to your duplication ?